# PHP use imagick. UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/715

Tags: php, imagick

I want to convert PDF to image and must use the Imagick of the PHP extension, but some errors occur. How can I fix it? Please help me.

p.s. the PHP version is 7.2

Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: Seems it's an internal error of Imagick. Have you tried to re-install / update the extension? How do you install the Imagick?

Comment: I followed this tutorial to do  [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-imagemagick-and-imagick-php-extension-in-ubuntu/) and had been 'extension=imagick' add to the php.ini file

Comment: Similar issue: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15350, you probably need to re-install & update the package. Also, you should update PHP version if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are a few cases for happens this problem:

**1. Permission problem. Make sure your folder's permission, chmod 0755.**

**2. Be sure extension imagemagick is suitable with PHP version.**

**3. Be sure delegates.xml file is exits.**

**4. After these check up PHP jpg/png GD is supporting.**